# How to Editing a PHP Page from line number and some identifier?

Tags: php

I want to replace **Data :** value from **Some Data** to **Some Other Data**, and **Method : ** from **Yes** to **No**. Where identifier is only **:** (colon) and after that there is new line.

```
<?php
/* 
Data : Some Data
Method : Yes
*/
?>
```

Is there any method in PHP which could do this?

I tried **substr** function, but it only separates the value from character length, and not suited for what 
I want.

Comment: learn regular expression and use `preg_replace`

Comment: Self-modifying PHP code is a really bad idea. Not only is it hostile to source code management and opcode caching, but it also has security implications -- it requires that your PHP scripts be writable by the web server, and it opens up the possibility of script injection if your code generation isn't perfect. Avoid it if at all possible.